# Connecting the GUI and Calculations in Qt Application

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am writing a Qt application which does some calculations. I would like **to separate in my project 2 parts: the part related to GUI and the part which is responsible for calculations**. Could you recommend the best way to do so? Examples are appreciated.

---

My idea was to do it in *main.cpp* file:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv); 

    MainWindow mw; // This is responsible for GUI
    mw.show();

    MainComputation mc; // This is responsible for calculations

    return app.exec();
}
```

I would need also to establish the connections between this two parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your `MainComputation` class as shown [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT) (mainly inherit from `QObject`, include the `Q_OBJECT` macro in your class declaration and label some methods as slots).

Then you will need to hook up signals and slots between your GUI elements signals (mouseClick, buttonPress, etc..., checkout each widgets available signals) and an instance of your `MainComputation` objects slots. This is done with the `connect` statement. Kinda like this

```
connect(mw.ui->btn,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),&mc,SLOT(doSomething()));
```

There is a simple example with a lot of information available at the [qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/signalsandslots.html#a-small-example).

Comment: I did it also in a way as you said. But introducing of signals and slots is a bit complicated, since my GUI's mainwindow subdivided into smaller objects(QWidgets).

Comment: Then you would have slots connected to those QWidgets signals.  It may seem complicated but it really is just self-documenting. If you do all of your connects in one location (usually right after all of the objects are instantiated), you essentially have a list of what the interface is. This also makes it very trivial to split up into multiple threads later on if it is deemed that you need that type of processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a library with the GUI, another library with the calculation algorithms, and exchange data between them using QT signals&slots.

Comment: Thank you for response, Jepessen. Could you give an example or where can I read how to do that?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html. Separate both abstractions, created an Qt object which act as adapter for your calculation library, and exchange data between this object and the ui.